# How do I detect tel: links added by mobile safari?

Tags: jquery, css, mobile-safari

We use jQuery to add a click handler to links that occur in part of our site, in order to track the event in Google analytics.  We're seeing that some events are coming in from links that we haven't put there, <s>and since they've all got HREFs along the lines of 1-234-567-890 I'm guessing the skype plugin has put them there</s> which I've learnt are being added by mobile safari.

At the moment, our selector looks like this:

```
links = $('.linksection a');
```

How should I change it to exclude the tel: links?

Comment: Interesting. Do the Skype links show up in the document inspector?

Comment: I don't have the plugin installed ATM.  I'm going to install it now to check, but I was hoping someone else might have dealt with this before.

Comment: ah - it's not skype, it's mobile safari.

Comment: +1 for fixing the answer after updating the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the plugin adds the links starting with tel:// you can use this code which filters out all links that start with tel:

```
$('a:not([href^="tel"])')
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/U2fR8/